# compound interest after 1, 3 and 5 years

Tags: java, math, calculator, rate

i have this code that calculates the compound interest, but i need it to do it for after 1, 3, and 5 years. ive tried and cant seem to get it to work. can anyone help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class CompoundInterest { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

double principal = 0; 
double rate = 0; 
double time = 0; 

double x = 0; 

System.out.print("Enter the amount invested : "); 
principal = input.nextDouble(); 

System.out.print("Enter the Rate of interest : "); 
rate = input.nextDouble(); 

System.out.print("Enter the Time of loan : "); 
time = input.nextDouble(); 


x = principal * Math.pow((1 + rate/12),time); 
 x = Math.pow(5,3);

System.out.println(""); 
System.out.println("The Compound Interest after 1 year is : " 
+ x); 

} 

}
```

Comment: http://qrc.depaul.edu/studyguide2009/notes/savings%20accounts/compound%20interest.htm

Answer (score 2):

Why do you set `x` to `principal *((1+r/12),time)`, then set `x=math.pow(5,3)`?

`x` is now set to `math.pow(5,3)` and has nothing to do with your inputs of principal, rate, and time.

Also, you should specify that the time input is years, as  you have that hard coded in the rate question.

Comment: No, no, it's months, not years, for this to work; but +1 for an otherwise correct answer.